# Loading a remote WP website to Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

I have a Worpdress blog on a hosting company (it's remote and existing).
I would like to load it to Netbeans.
How do I do that?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. File > New Project
2. Categories select 'PHP'
3. Project select 'PHP Application from Remote Server'
4. click 'Next' and give the project a name and specify where local/downloaded files will be stored.
5. click next
6. Enter Project URL, and upload path on remote server (this probably be just / if WP is installed at root of the domain)
7. Here you'd need to specify how you will be connecting to remote server. Click 'Manage' button next to 'Remote Connection'
8. click 'Add' button to create a new remote connection and enter all the FTP/SFTP details and click OK
9. Click next until the end of the wizard

Comment: What would you do for the database stuff?